# Which backend does the QSVM run on?

Tags: qiskit, machine-learning

I'm trying to create a QSVM classifier model. I wanted to know which backend the fit() method uses to train the model. I checked on the IBM portal to see if there were any jobs being created, but there were none.

Also, is there a way to specify the backend on which the model will be trained?

Comment: In Qiskit you choose your own backend no? If they're somehow handling that for you, it's likely just a simulation. I doubt you would get any meaningful results trying to run the QSVM on an actual device.

Comment: Hi, although you have quite a good answer, I would advise you next time to put much more details in your question, for example maybe the qiskit version you are using, or a snippet of your code, or more details about the problem you want to solve/you face, just to have a better idea of what you're trying to do so the answer can be more specific :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'm not sure the `QSVM` class is still part of Qiskit. There is no reference to it to be found in the documentation. It has likely been superseded by [the `QSVC` class](https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/stubs/qiskit_machine_learning.algorithms.QSVC.html). See [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/migration/01_migration_guide_0.5.html) for how to train a QSVC in the latest version of Qiskit.

Then, we can go to Qiskit's Github repository in order to find [the source code of this class](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-machine-learning/blob/c660b1104be77fb29449a2b96f13867c1a2a8cde/qiskit_machine_learning/algorithms/classifiers/qsvc.py#L26):

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC

class QSVC(SVC, SerializableModelMixin):
    [...]
    def __init__(self, *args, quantum_kernel: Optional[BaseKernel] = None, **kwargs):
        [...]
        super().__init__(kernel=self._quantum_kernel.evaluate, *args, **kwargs)
```

So, what it does it simply using the `SVC` class from `sklearn` with kernel `self._quantum_kernel.evaluate`. This is expected: the computational advantage of an SVC comes from the kernel evaluation.

Thus, the backend which is used is defined in the kernel that is used. For instance, for the `FidelityQuantumKernel`, one can see [in the source code](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-machine-learning/blob/c660b1104be77fb29449a2b96f13867c1a2a8cde/qiskit_machine_learning/kernels/fidelity_quantum_kernel.py#L28):

```
def __init__(
    self,
    *,
    feature_map: QuantumCircuit | None = None,
    fidelity: BaseStateFidelity | None = None,
    enforce_psd: bool = True,
    evaluate_duplicates: str = "off_diagonal",
) -> None:
    [...]
    if fidelity is None:
        fidelity = ComputeUncompute(sampler=Sampler())
    self._fidelity = fidelity
```

So, under the hood, the computation uses the `fidelity` argument, which is an instance of `BaseStateFidelity`. For instance, if one uses the [`ComputeUncompute` class](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.algorithms.state_fidelities.ComputeUncompute.html#qiskit.algorithms.state_fidelities.ComputeUncompute), then one needs to pass a `Sampler` instance as an argument, which finally gives the answer.

If you're not familiar with Qiskit primitives, I encourage you to [read about it in the documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/primitives.html), in particular [the Sampler page](https://qiskit.org/documentation/partners/qiskit_ibm_runtime/tutorials/how-to-getting-started-with-sampler.html). What's important to note is that you can specify the backend that will be used by creating a `Session` instance with a context manager and creating your `Sampler` instance inside it, like this:

```
with Session(service=service, backend="ibmq_qasm_simulator"):
    sampler = Sampler()
```

Now, you have to be careful with the `Sampler` class, since they are two of them. The one which is used by default in the `FidelityQuantumKernel` is the one that lives in Qiskit, which, as mentioned in the documentation of the `Sampler` primitive, uses a local classical simulator. If you wish to change the backend, be sure to use the `Sampler` class from the `qiksit_ibm_runtime` package, as mentioned in the aforementioned documentation.